# Requesitng 1000's of websites as fast as possible C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm here to ask a small question. I need to make 1000's of HttpWebRequests, all at the same template, Idk what should I use to make them run as fast as possible. I also have a proxylist that I pick randomly the proxies from.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            randomIndex = Urls.rnd.Next(0, Proxies.proxies.Count() - 1);
            string proxy = Proxies.proxies[randomIndex];
            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
            request.Proxy = myProxy;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            response.Close();
            response = null;
            request = null;
            myProxy = null;
            proxy = null;
            randomIndex = 0;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you do that? At first glance at your question it seems like you're trying to create some sort of malware. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: @Maritim Or maybe it is just for some kind of stress test

Comment: Not of any kind, you wouldn't DoS or anything with proxies, it's legit and it's for educational purposes, as I need to use them in a FIFO order.

Comment: As I said, please prove me wrong. And you did!

Comment: I would look towards Async Tasks in C#, i'm not entirely sure why you are limited to FIFO but maybe you could clarify your problem a little more

Comment: I don't know how to explain this. This is something API related. Either way the FIFO order is not determined by the ending of the request but the FIFO order is supposed to be the order how it will call the functions to process the urls

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to make a pool of threads and then create a dictionary of web clients. On a 4 core machine 35 or so threads is good. Use a ConcurrentQueue and queue actions on to it. Then for each of your threads have them in a while(true) loop that does a TryDequeue sleep for about 200 ms in the thread while loop.